# Unable to load a Keras saved model (Error: unable to open file)

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

i trained a keras sequential model on colab and saved it to the TensorFlow SavedModel format.
Then i download zipped folder of trained model (containing saved_model.pb file and variable subfolder) to my computer and tried to load this model in one of my python files but ended up with
this error:  (N.B: i run my python file from an anaconda custom environment with both keras and tensorflow installed)

```
OSError: Unable to open file (unable to open file: name = 'C:/Users/user/Desktop/chiffre.model', errno = 13, error message = 'Permission denied', flags = 0, o_flags = 0)
```

This is the training and saving code on colab:

```
import numpy as np
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras import layers

model = keras.Sequential(..................)
#some lines of code
model.save('chiffre.model')
```

and i tried to load the model in python file with:

```
new_model = keras.models.load_model('C:/Users/user/Desktop/chiffre.model',custom_objects=None,compile=True)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this,

```
model.save("my_model")
```

Calling *model.save('my_model')* creates a folder named my_model, containing the following:

```
assets  saved_model.pb  variables
```

The model architecture, and training configuration (including the optimizer, losses, and metrics) are stored in saved_model.pb. The weights are saved in the variables/ directory.

For loading model then,

```
reconstructed_model = keras.models.load_model("my_model")
```

**OR**,
You can also save a single HDF5 file containing the model's architecture, weights values, and compile() information. It is a light-weight alternative to SavedModel.

```
# Calling `save('my_model.h5')` creates a h5 file `my_model.h5`.
model.save("my_h5_model.h5")
```

For loading with this method,

```
# It can be used to reconstruct the model identically.
reconstructed_model = keras.models.load_model("my_h5_model.h5")
```

Comment: Thanks i saved the model into a h5 format but when if loaded it  now i have this error :   ValueError: Unknown layer:name

Comment: Try updating Keras. 'conda update keras' or upgrade via pip. This error is commonly seen with Keras v2.0. Upgrading may resolve it.

Comment: i just installed keras and tensorflow today so i have last version of both

Comment: to confirm ::::::::: (tens) C:\Users\user>conda update keras
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: done

# All requested packages already installed.